# How do i make my icons spread neatly in linear layout?

Tags: android

There is a gap on my action bar on the right after i put the icons. How do i evenly spread the icons? 
Here's a screen shot

[image]

and my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/menu" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/menu" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/menu" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Give weight to every ImageButton as 1

Comment: android:layout_weight="1" for all the image buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: `android:layout_weight="1"` for each of them

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/menu" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/menu"
        android:layout_weight=".25" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu"
         android:layout_weight=".25"  />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu" 
         android:layout_weight=".25" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/menu" 
         android:layout_weight=".25" />

    </LinearLayout>
```